# I find it hard to imagine that

Tags: sentence-structure

This is an excerpt from a [*The Atlantic* article](https://www.theatlantic.com/culture/archive/2022/02/gun-safety-hollywood-alec-baldwin/622836/).

> “I find it hard to imagine **that** in a culture where we are more ready
> to ban books than we are to ban guns that we’re suddenly going to stop
> having gun shootouts in movies.”

I think the **that** in bold could be removed from the sentence because I think the object of 'imagine' is *"that we’re suddenly going to stop having gun shootouts in movies."*

Am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it should be removed?

Comment: I think the object of 'imagine' is "that we’re suddenly going to stop having gun shootouts in movies". Am I wrong?

Comment: I rolled back the edit because it came after gotube's answer which suggested rephrasing the original sentence. Moreover, the [*that* -clause](https://www.thoughtco.com/that-clause-definition-1692539#:~:text=In%20English%20grammar%2C%20a%20%22%20that,appositive%20in%20a%20declarative%20sentence.) in bold is the first one,  but in the reordered sentence you kept it in.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you very much.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are correct in saying that “that we’re suddenly going to stop having gun shootouts in movies” is the object of “imagine”. However, what do we do with “in a culture where we are more ready to ban books than we are to ban guns”? That is also part of the object clause and thus should follow the subordinating conjunction “that”. We should therefore eliminate the **second** “that”:

> I find it hard to imagine that in a culture where we are more ready to ban books than we are to ban guns we’re suddenly going to stop having gun shootouts in movies.

If we consider the first prepositional phrase to be nonrestrictive, then we can surround it with paired punctuation:

> I find it hard to imagine that, in a culture where we are more ready to ban books than we are to ban guns, we’re suddenly going to stop having gun shootouts in movies.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

You're right, and there's a better way to fix it, and... this sentence is still kinda correct.

**Why you're right**

This sentence can be reordered like this:

> [In a culture where we are more ready to ban books than we are to ban guns], I find it hard to imagine [that we’re suddenly going to stop having gun shootouts in movies].

It's clear from this form that you're right: *"that ... in movies"* is the object of "imagine", and the word "that" is duplicated.

**A better way to fix it**

The sentence can also be fixed either by replacing the **second** "that" with a comma:

> I find it hard to imagine that in a culture where we are more ready to ban books than we are to ban gun, **<del>that</del>** we’re suddenly going to stop having gun shootouts in movies.

... or by reordering it another way:

> I find it hard to imagine [that we’re suddenly going to stop having gun shootouts in movies] [in a culture where we are more ready to ban books than we are to ban guns].

This second fix preserves a nuance in the original. In the original, the writer presents two concepts and contrasts them as hard to imagine existing together: ["in a culture..."] and ["we're suddenly going to stop..."]. In your fix, however, the context of "in a culture..." restricts the writer's thinking, as in "because I'm in a culture where... , I find it hard to imagine...". This is not how she wrote the sentence, and fixing it this way preserves that nuance.

**Why it's still (kinda) correct**

BUT... this speech pattern of duplicating "that" is quite common. It helps both the speaker and the listener follow the flow of a very long and complex sentence. The first "that" introduces the context of what the speaker cannot imagine, and the second "that" introduces the grammatical object of "imagine". Even though I know the grammar is incorrect, when speaking, I myself would find it hard NOT to insert the second "that" if I were saying this sentence.

I'm not sure it's great writing style. It could have been reworded as I did above without losing any nuance. But the writer might have intended the piece to have the feel of a personal conversation, rather than a typical serious Atlantic article (The article itself is behind a paywall, so I can't compare the overall tone with this sentence).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @ELL Pleasure! Also give MarcInManhattan's answer some love. It explains the middle part better and with fewer words.

Comment: @gotube I hadn’t seen your answer when I posted mine a few minutes later. I think we’re saying basically the same thing.

Comment: I think this answer is better, for explaining the last part why this duplicating "that" is in use. But the other answer is good too.